# Guideline for writing callbacks via various tricks

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am confused in deciding whether I should use

- a polymorphic (via overriding the virtual method `A`) method.
- a delegate-type-parameterized method `B`.
- an event `C`.
- an instance of a class implementing an interface with a single method `D`. A Java's trick!

when writing callbacks.

```
using System;

namespace CallBack
{
    interface IOptional
    {
        void D();
    }

    class Base
    {
        protected virtual void A() => Console.WriteLine("Base's extra jobs.");
        public void Do(Action B = null, IOptional optional = null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Base's main jobs.");

            // and call the optional jobs
            A();
            B?.Invoke();
            C?.Invoke();
            optional?.D();
        }
        public event Action C;
    }


    class Derived : Base
    {
        protected override void A()
        {
            base.A();

            Console.WriteLine("Derived's extra jobs.");
        }
    }

    class Optional : IOptional
    {
        public void D()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("D");
        }
    }

    class Test
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            Derived d = new Derived();
            d.C += () => Console.WriteLine("C");
            d.Do(() => Console.WriteLine("B"), new Optional());
        }
    }
}
```

## Question

Is there any commonly used guideline for agile programmers?

Comment: No, please don't migrate this question. It would be closed there.

Comment: Something to consider is: how would the question be different if it did not involve a *push*, but instead was a *pull*?  When you have a class with a value `X` that must be read, do you implement (1) a field, (2) a property, (3) an interface with a property, (4) a method, (5) an interface with a method?  I think the answer to that question would be "it depends on the needs of the code doing the pulling". Pushing is the same; the needs of the client drive the design.

Comment: @EricLippert: Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use cases of the three seem quite distinct to me :)

The core idea is "who do you want to let know about the event".

If you want to allow *everyone* to be able to subscribe to it, use an `event`. This is also what most of .NET that I have experience with deal with callbacks.

By using the polymorphism approach, you only allow subclasses to know about the event. If some other object wants to do something when it happens, it can't, because it's not a subclass and can't override the method.

By using the delegate parameter approach, you limit the number of subscribers to 1. Any caller can subscribe to the event, but subscriber-event is now a one-to-one relationship.

Comment: @MoneyOrientedProgrammer You shouldn't really edit your question to ask about something new... Java's "trick" only exists because Java doesn't have delegates. C# has delegates, so you would always choose to use a delegate parameter or an event instead. That said, Java 8 now has lambdas, so Java's trick is seen less often even in Java.